# How to replace name attribute inside of element in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following issue:
I have Jquery element `Tournament.player` with following data:

```html
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col">
    <input name="players[2][nickname]" type="text" class="form-control" id="p_nickname" placeholder="Nickname" value="Player3">
  </div>
  <div class="col p_region" style="">
    <select name="players[2][region]" class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose region</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <button type="button" class="w-100 btn-sm btn-danger deleteRow">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to increment counter in **name** attribute of inner select and input elements.

That's what I tried so far:

```js
var newPlayer = Tournament.player.clone().find('input, select').attr("name", function(i, name) {
  return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function($0, $1) {
    return +$1 + 1;
  });
});
newPlayer.appendTo(".players");
```

It does what I need, but returns only select and input elements, like so:

```
<input name="players[3][nickname]" type="text" class="form-control" id="p_nickname" placeholder="Nickname" value="">
<select name="players[3][region]" class="form-control" disabled="">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose region</option>                                                                               
</select>
```

What I do wrong? I want to get same element that I had before, but getting only part of it.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! Tournament.player is a variable, that has JQuery element  inside (I've provided it in my question). Hope now its clear

Comment: I'm finding it on the page and copy in variable for future use:
`this.player = $(".player:last").clone()
            .find("input")
            .attr({value: ''})
            .end(); `

Comment: @mplungjan
Yes, It is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this:

```js
const Tournament = {
  player: $(".mb-2")
}

var newPlayer = Tournament.player.clone();
newPlayer.find('input, select').attr("name", function(i, name) {
  return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function($0, $1) {
    return +$1 + 1;
  });
});
newPlayer.find('input').attr("value", function(i, value) {
  return value.replace(/(\d+)/, function($0, $1) {
    return +$1 + 1;
  });
});
newPlayer.appendTo(".players");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="players">
  <div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col">
      <input name="players[2][nickname]" type="text" class="form-control" id="p_nickname" placeholder="Nickname" value="Player2">
    </div>
    <div class="col p_region" style="">
      <select name="players[2][region]" class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose region</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <button type="button" class="w-100 btn-sm btn-danger deleteRow">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. I guess, there was wrong methods chain in my code!

Comment: Yes, you inserted only the found elements